# ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : How to uninstall Flyway from Spring Maven Project

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, uninstallation, flyway

The goal: Uninstall flyway from my Spring Maven project !

Maybe my question is more global and consists of how to get rid of dependecies or libraries....

The context:
My project is called "Meetzicker" it will be a restfull API to meet musicians.
I will dockerize it and use docker-compose with many services:

- my API
- postgres db
- pgAdmin to manage DB
- and later flyway but not for now !

If you have advices I accept them gladly !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UdFP.png)

First I build an image of my project with the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.praline40</groupId>
    <artifactId>meetzicker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>MeetZicker REST API</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.18.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version> 2.0.1.Final </version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>




    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <build>
                                <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerFileDir>
                                <assembly>
                                    <mode>dir</mode>
                                    <targetDir>/var/lib/${project.artifactId}</targetDir>
                                    <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                </assembly>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

The last part of the pom (between  ... ) builds my image automatically when I call:

```
~/Documents/MeetZicker/BACK/MeetZicker/MeetZicker$ mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
```

I am using docker-composed with 3 services:

```
# meetzicker/docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}
    container_name: db
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: pgadmin4
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    expose:
      - 5050
    ports:
      - 5051:5050
    links:
      - db:pgsql-server
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: praline40@hotmail.fr
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      PGADMIN_PORT: 5050
    restart: unless-stopped

  meetzicker:
    image: meetzicker
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: meetzicker
    volumes:
      - meetzicker-data:/var/lib/meetzicker
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - db


volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  meetzicker-data:
```

When I call docker-compose:

```
jules@jules-MS-7B51:~/Documents/MeetZicker/BACK/MeetZicker/MeetZicker/src/main/docker$ docker-compose up
```

I have this error:

```
jules@jules-MS-7B51:~/Documents/MeetZicker/BACK/MeetZicker/MeetZicker/src/main/docker$ docker-compose up
WARNING: Found orphan containers (my-flyway) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
db is up-to-date
Starting pgadmin4   ... done
Starting meetzicker ... done
Attaching to db, meetzicker, pgadmin4
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
db            | 
db            | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db            | 
db            | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-14 13:52:50 UTC
db            | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db            | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db            | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-14 14:16:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-14 14:16:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-14 14:16:16 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-14 14:16:16 +0000] [82] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 82
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
meetzicker    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
meetzicker    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
meetzicker    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
meetzicker    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
meetzicker    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
meetzicker    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:29.399  INFO 43 --- [           main] c.p.MeetZicker.MeetZickerApplication     : Starting MeetZickerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on c9ed3b2b0bd9 with PID 43 (/var/lib/meetzicker/meetzicker.jar started by root in /var/lib/meetzicker)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:29.401  INFO 43 --- [           main] c.p.MeetZicker.MeetZickerApplication     : The following profiles are active: dev
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:29.849  INFO 43 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:29.918  INFO 43 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 62ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.323  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.331  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.331  INFO 43 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.368  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.368  INFO 43 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 936 ms
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.445  WARN 43 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'flywayInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingException: Cannot find migration scripts in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migration scripts or check your Flyway configuration)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.447  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.453  INFO 43 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:30.454 ERROR 43 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | ***************************
meetzicker    | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
meetzicker    | ***************************
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Description:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    |         - classpath:db/migration
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Action:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Review the locations above or check your Flyway configuration
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
meetzicker    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
meetzicker    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
meetzicker    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
meetzicker    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
meetzicker    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
meetzicker    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:46.742  INFO 44 --- [           main] c.p.MeetZicker.MeetZickerApplication     : Starting MeetZickerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on c9ed3b2b0bd9 with PID 44 (/var/lib/meetzicker/meetzicker.jar started by root in /var/lib/meetzicker)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:46.743  INFO 44 --- [           main] c.p.MeetZicker.MeetZickerApplication     : The following profiles are active: dev
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.199  INFO 44 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.268  INFO 44 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.673  INFO 44 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.681  INFO 44 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.681  INFO 44 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.719  INFO 44 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.719  INFO 44 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 945 ms
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.811  WARN 44 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'flywayInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingException: Cannot find migration scripts in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migration scripts or check your Flyway configuration)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.813  INFO 44 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.819  INFO 44 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-14 14:16:47.820 ERROR 44 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | ***************************
meetzicker    | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
meetzicker    | ***************************
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Description:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    |         - classpath:db/migration
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Action:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Review the locations above or check your Flyway configuration
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker exited with code 1
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
```

¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

I removed orphans:

```
jules@jules-MS-7B51:~/Documents/MeetZicker/BACK/MeetZicker/MeetZicker/src/main/docker$ docker-compose up --remove-orphans
Removing orphan container "my-flyway"
Starting db ... done
Starting meetzicker ... done
Starting pgadmin4   ... done
Attaching to db, meetzicker, pgadmin4
db            | 
db            | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db            | 
db            | LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2021-05-16 12:21:00 UTC
db            | LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
db            | LOG:  invalid record length at 0/14F1D38: wanted 24, got 0
db            | LOG:  redo is not required
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
db            | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db            | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db            | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-17 11:09:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-17 11:09:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-17 11:09:31 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: threads
pgadmin4      | [2021-05-17 11:09:31 +0000] [83] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 83
meetzicker    | wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
meetzicker    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
meetzicker    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
meetzicker    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
meetzicker    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
meetzicker    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
meetzicker    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.061  INFO 43 --- [           main] c.p.MeetZicker.MeetZickerApplication     : Starting MeetZickerApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on d256a05b5f82 with PID 43 (/var/lib/meetzicker/meetzicker.jar started by root in /var/lib/meetzicker)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.062  INFO 43 --- [           main] c.p.MeetZicker.MeetZickerApplication     : The following profiles are active: dev
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.512  INFO 43 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.581  INFO 43 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 63ms. Found 12 JPA repository interfaces.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.988  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.996  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:44.996  INFO 43 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:45.032  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:45.032  INFO 43 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 939 ms
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:45.123  WARN 43 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'flywayInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingException: Cannot find migration scripts in: [classpath:db/migration] (please add migration scripts or check your Flyway configuration)
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:45.125  INFO 43 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:45.131  INFO 43 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
meetzicker    | 2021-05-17 11:09:45.133 ERROR 43 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | ***************************
meetzicker    | APPLICATION FAILED TO START
meetzicker    | ***************************
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Description:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    |         - classpath:db/migration
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Action:
meetzicker    | 
meetzicker    | Review the locations above or check your Flyway configuration
meetzicker    |
```

Here is my public project:

https://github.com/praline40/MeetZickerAPI

Comment: Paste you application.yml|properties files, any chance u activate the flyway there.

Comment: I can't find this file. I just have a .iml

Comment: Where is this file ?

Comment: Have u looked at warning while running docker compose `WARNING: Found orphan containers (my-flyway) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
db is up-to-date`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I saw it ! I does not influence anything. I have removed orphans.

Comment: I posted my project here: https://github.com/praline40/MeetZickerAPI

Comment: Please help me I am going mad !

Comment: try adding `spring.flyway.enabled=false` into your application properties file

Comment: I did it already, it does not do anything. The problem comes from an external library : org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class

Comment: The main question is: WHERE in my project I call Flyway.

Comment: Nobody have an Idea ? Where can I call flyway in my project if not in the pom.xml file ?

Comment: Nobody can help me ? I am still totally blocked. 

I can't find where in my project I call Flyway and its dependencies. 

It is not in the pom.xml anymore, neither in any classes. 

My problem must not be one for someone who knows IntelliJ and Spring well. 

I am sure it deals with persistent dependencies, maybe in cache or something else. 

Thanks.